# React Gatsbyjs - Passing props with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have an issue in a GatsbyJS project with styled components. I am passing a prop into `ContentBlock` component that should then be passed on to the styled `StyledContentBlock` component, which should adapt based on the value of the prop.

However this does not work. The CSS never changes and setting `fullWidth` to `true` has no effect.

the `ContentBlock` component:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import device from "../shared/devices"
import H2 from "./h2"

const StyledContentBlock = styled.div`
  @media ${device.mobile} {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
  }

  @media ${device.tablet} {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: ${props => props.fullWidth ? 7 : 4};
  }
`

const ContentBlockHeading = styled(H2)`
  @media ${device.mobile} {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  @media ${device.tablet} {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  @media ${device.desktop} {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  }
`

const ContentBlock = ({ title, fullWidth, children }) => (
  <StyledContentBlock>
    <ContentBlockHeading>{title}</ContentBlockHeading>
    {children}
  </StyledContentBlock>
);

ContentBlock.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  fullWidth: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

ContentBlock.defaultProps = {
  title: '',
  fullWidth: false,
}

export default ContentBlock
```

Using it on a page:

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import ContentBlock from "../components/content-block"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <ContentBlock title="Some title">
    </ContentBlock>
    <ContentBlock title="Some other title" fullWidth>
    </ContentBlock>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

I'm out of wit. What is going on here? I also tried not using pattern matching and accessing the props object directly. To no effect:

```
const ContentBlock = (props) => (
  // etc
```

Comment: Yes. Silly me. Thanks!

Comment: Just made my comment an answer, sorry for having deleting it :)

Comment: pass the props , i hope that will solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try passing the props to the styled component

```
const ContentBlock = (props) => (
  <StyledContentBlock {...props}>
    <ContentBlockHeading>{props.title}</ContentBlockHeading>
    {props.children}
  </StyledContentBlock>
);
```

or pass with destructuring

```
const ContentBlock = ({ title, fullWidth, children }) => (
  <StyledContentBlock fullWidth={fullWidth}>
    <ContentBlockHeading>{title}</ContentBlockHeading>
    {children}
  </StyledContentBlock>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass any prop to `StyledContentBlock`, try this :

```
const ContentBlock = ({ title, fullWidth, children }) => (
  <StyledContentBlock fullWidth={fullWidth}>
    <ContentBlockHeading>{title}</ContentBlockHeading>
    {children}
  </StyledContentBlock>
);
```

As seen in the docs : https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props